# How to restrict user to do rating only once..i m using AjaxControlToolkit Rating Control i VB.NET !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to restrict user to do rating only once..i m using AjaxControlToolkit Rating Control i VB.NET !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an anonymous user, you can only do so much, like store a cookie in the user's browser after they have rated once.  That won't prevent the anonymous user from clearing their cookies or using another browser and voting again.

If it's not an anonymous user, you can store whether or not the user has rated in your database and perform a check when the user access the rating page to disable the rating option.